# How to find and delete duplicates in one column based on values from another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have loaded 2 excel files. Each excel file contains a data frame.
First df looks like this:

```
number
091239
091212
092233
```

Second df2 looks like this:

```
name number
R    2340
K    092233
S    345
L    091212
```

How can I find duplicates based on a column "number" of the first df in the second df2?

Because I am learning dplyr I would greatly appreciate dplyr solutions.

I have tried this code

```
 filtered <- df2%>%
distinct(number, df$number, .keep_all = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to filter for the duplicates:

```
filter(df2, df2$number %in% df$number == TRUE)
```

You can change it to FALSE also if you want to keep rows where the values are not in df1

Answer (score 0):

Something like `inner_join` might do the trick here:

```
inner_join(df2, df1, by = "number")
```